# How to modify this query so start/end dates go by days instead of exact times?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, timestamp

I'm using the query below to get posts based on the start and end dates which use the UNIX timestamp.

Currently, it's only returning results if the start time occurred after today's time. For example, if it's 5:00 PM and the start date is 6:00 PM, it won't pick it up. I would like it to consider anytime during today (from midnight last night to midnight tonight) as being the start date.

Can someone tell me how to update my code to get this to work?

`$current_time` is equal to `1305132894`, which is 5:54 EST today.

```
'meta_query'        => array(
    array(
        'key'       => 'start_date',
        'value'     => $current_time,
        'compare'   => '<'
    ),
    array(
        'key'       => 'end_date',
        'value'     => $current_time,
        'compare'   => '>'
    )
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only need it to work for today, you can use:

```
$minDate = strtotime('midnight today');
$maxDate = strtotime('midnight tomorrow -1 second');
```

or alternatively

```
$minDate = mktime(0,0,0);
$maxDate = mktime(11,59,59);
```

Some combination of [`mktime()`](http://php.net/mktime) and [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) should work.

Comment: This seems to work, however it's returning GMT time. How can I set it to go by CST?

Comment: For example, if I set the time to May 12, 2011 at 8:00 PM, it doesn't pick up the result as occurring today. How can I offset the hours by X number from GMT?

Comment: Your best bet is to use `date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');`

Comment: It is also possible to pass timezone arguments to `strtotime()`, e.g. `strtotime('midnight today GMT-0500')`,`strtotime('midnight today CST')` and `strtotime('midnight today CDT')`

Answer (score 0):

Considering your example: `$current_time = 1305132894`

This should answer your question:

```
$date_current = date("Y-m-d",1305132894);  //2011-05-11
$date_midnight = strtotime($date_current . "00:00:00"); //1305061200 that means: 2011-05-11 00:00:00
```

So replace $current time by $date_midnight and you'll have anytime during today from midnight last night.

Comment: That seems to be working (as far as returning the same day and 00:00:00), however how do I make it so the start date knows it's today? For example, since start_date is greater than $date_midnight, it's not being picked up in the results.

Comment: I didn't notice the other answer. It fits better your question. So they answered already :)
good luck